# Simulate probit marginal effects with an interaction term

Tags: r, simulation, marginal-distribution, probit

I have the following probit model:

```
library(foreign)
library(MASS)

data <- read.dta("Braith_statecap_JPR.dta")
data <- data[data$year > 1959,]

model1 <- glm(allons3 ~ confbord + rpc + confbord_rpc + neighlgdp + polity2l + polity2sq + lgdp96l + lnpop + postcoldw + peaceall, data = data, family = "binomial"(link = "probit"))
```

The data along with a stata do file can be downloaded at:

[Journal of Peace Research: Bratithwaite](http://www.prio.no/misc/Download.aspx?file=/cscw/rd/Replication%20Data/Braithwaite%20-%20%2047%283%29.zip/Braithwaite%20-%20Replication%20Data%2047%283%29.zip)

The paper can be found at:

[Braithwaite2010](http://jpr.sagepub.com/content/47/3/311.short)

In the paper from which the data is taken, the author simulates the effects of the interaction term in the model (the confbord_rpc term, the multiplication has been done in advance). "confbord" is a dummy variable and "rpc" ranges from 0 to 7. He first calculates the effects with "confbord" set to 0, and "rpc" varying from 0 to 7 (everything else held constant at their means), and then subtracts the effects from the same models with "confbord" held constant at 1. He obtains a very substantial effect from the "cpr" variable through this procedure. I have been replicating this using the following code:

```
    #simulate coefficients based on the model
    beta <- coef(model1)
    covvar <- summary(model1)$cov.unscaled
    coefs.sim <- mvrnorm(10000, beta, covvar)

    #let rpc vary hold confbord constant at 0, and the other variables at their means
    constant <- 1
    confbord <- 0
    rpc <- seq(0,7,1)
    ncivwar_rpc <- ncivwar * rpc
    neighlgdp <- 8.077
    polity2l <- -0.4691
    polity2sq <- 56.51
    lgdp96l <- 8.123 
    lnpop <- 9.028
    postcoldw  <- 0
    peaceall <- 16.14

    #bind them together in a matrix   
    effects0 <- cbind(constant,ncivwar,rpc, ncivwar_rpc, neighlgdp, polity2l, polity2sq, lgdp96l, lnpop, postcoldw, peaceall)

    #multiply the effects matrix with the matrix of simulated coefficients to obtain marginal effects
    results0 <- coefs.sim %*% t(effects0)

    #evaluate each marginal effect on the standardized normal CDF, to obtain predicted probabilities
    results0 <- apply(results0,1:2, function(x) pnorm(x))

    #do the same procedure for confbord held constant at 1
    constant <- 1
    confbord <- 1
    rcp <- seq(0,7,1)
    ncivwar_rpc <- ncivwar * rpc
    neighlgdp <- 8.077
    polity2l <- -0.4691
    polity2sq <- 56.51
    lgdp96l <- 8.123 
    lnpop <- 9.028
    postcoldw  <- 0
    peaceall <- 16.14

    effects1 <- cbind(constant,ncivwar,rpc, ncivwar_rpc, neighlgdp, polity2l, polity2sq, lgdp96l, lnpop, postcoldw, peaceall)
    results1 <- coefs.sim %*% t(effects1)
    results1 <- apply(results1,1:2,function(x) pnorm(x))

    # subtract the estimated probabilities from each other
    results <- results1 - results0

    #graph the results
    x <- seq(0,7,1)
    means <- apply(results,2,mean)
    sdUpper <- apply(results,2,function(x) quantile(x, .975))
    sdLower <- apply(results,2,function(x) quantile(x, .025))
    plot(x,means, ylim = c(-1,.2), type = "l")
    lines(x,sdUpper, lty = 2)
    lines(x,sdLower, lty = 2)
    lines(x,rep(0,8), col = "red")
```

The problem is that with this procedure I get a much lower effect than the author reports in the paper (figure 1), can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ran the regression for Fig. 2 that uses `confbord` variable, but you try to get the margins from regression for Fig. 1 that uses `nciwvar` variable.

Comment: The Stata code looks rather inefficient, even accounting for it being four versions old. These days, all this machinery is bundled in `margins` and `marginsplot`, and they produce results that are quite different from what's published in the paper. Approaching this by simulation sounded a bit odd to me. This looks more like a job for Stata's `nlcom`. Ah well... it's not my paper that we are looking at here :)